# Request with Alamofire

Tags: json, swift, xcode, get, alamofire

I'm starting on swift and I'm trying to bring a list of cars with alamofire but it is not bringing 
The code executes without throwing errors but not the list
I see a blank table view

https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/simulator_screen_shot_-_iphone_8_-_2019-10-20_at_16-48-23-png

## (sorry... editing with the write code)

My classes

```
struct HotelData: Codable  {
    let results: [Results]
}

struct Results: Codable  {
    let smallDescription: String
    let price: Price
    let gallery: [ImageHotel]
    let name: String
    let address: Address

    var getRandonImage: ImageHotel {
        let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(gallery.count)))
        return gallery[index]
    }
}
```

==============

My manager

```
class func getHotels(onComplete: @escaping (HotelData?) -> Void) {
        AF.request(path).responseJSON { (response) in
            guard let jsonData = response.data else { return }
            guard let hotelData = try? JSONDecoder().decode(HotelData.self, from: jsonData)
                else {
                    onComplete(nil)
                    return
            }
            onComplete(hotelData)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

==============

Cell

```
func prepareCell(with hotel: Results){
        lbName.text = hotel.name
        lbSmallDescription.text = hotel.smallDescription
        lbPrice.text = "R$ \(hotel.price.amount)"
        lbAdress.text = hotel.address.city
    }
```

==============

TableView
            class HotelTableViewController: UITableViewController {

```
            var hotels: [Results] = []
            let hotelManager = HotelManager()

            override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()
                loadHotels()
            }


            override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
                super.viewWillAppear(animated)

            }


            override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
                return 1
            }


            override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
                return hotels.count

            }


            override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! HotelTableViewCell
                let hotel = hotels[indexPath.row]
                cell.prepareCell(with: hotel)
                return cell
                }


            func loadHotels() {
                HotelManager.getHotels { (hotelData) in
                    if let hotelData = hotelData {
                        self.hotels += hotelData.results
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Post the code you have as part of your question and explain what the issue is with it.

Comment: What is the definition of your CarData struct? It is not present in your code above. And What is your exact problem? Weren't you able to fetch the data from the internet? Or not able to parse the response json got?

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] that reproduces your problem?  See [ask] which suggests, *Help others reproduce the problem... Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.  If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but also copy the code into the question itself.*

Comment: sorry, code edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your direct issue is that you need to call `reloadData()` if you want your `UITableView` to look at your downloaded data and load the appropriate cells. You can put in the completion handler of your network call, or in a `didSet` on your `hotels` property.

Additionally, you shouldn't use `responseJSON` for `Decodable` types, it's redundant. Instead you should use `responseDecodable` and pass the type you want to parse: `responseDecodable(of: HotelData.self) { response in ... }`.